# Show that $f(x)$ is surjective or not

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Prove/disprove: $f(x)$ is surjective if $f(x) = \frac{5x + 1}{x - 2}$ and $f: \mathbb{R} -\{ 2\} \to  \mathbb{R} -\{ 5\}$

**Discovery:**
Solving for $y$, I get $x = \frac{2y + 1}{y - 5}$.

**PROOF:**
Let $x = \frac{2y + 1}{y - 5}$, $y \ne 5$

Then $f(x) = y$ for $y \ne 5, x\ne 2$. Thus $f$ is surjective.

correct?

Comment: Correct indeed.

Comment: Right! you have actually proved that $f$ is a bijection of $\mathbb{R} -\{ 2\}$ onto  $\mathbb{R} -\{ 5\}$.

Answer (score 1):

we have

$f(x)=5+\frac{11}{x-2}$

let $y\in \mathbb R$

we look for $x$ such that

$5+\frac{11}{x-2}=y$ or

$\frac{11}{x-2}=y-5$

so if $y\neq 5$ then

$x=2+\frac{11}{y-5}$

so $f$ is a surjection from $\mathbb R-\{2\}$ to

$\mathbb R-\{5\}$  and since

$x$ is unique,

$f$ is a bijection from $ \mathbb R-\{2\}$
to $\mathbb R-\{5\}$.